# Cant figure out how to set up up a static resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid that I am trying to hook up a visibility converter to.  I have a class set up in the HelperObjects namespace, but for some reason the xaml is not picking up the reference.  The error message is "The resource BoolToVisConverter could not be resolved"  Why won't the xaml pull in this resource?  I am sure I am doing something ridiculous here...

Here is the xaml:

```
 xmlns:HelperObjects="clr-namespace:foo.HelperObjects"

    ...

   <Grid Visibility="{Binding isZoneTwoVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is indicating that the resource identified by the key `BoolToVisConverter`, to which you're trying to bind, cannot be found.

The most likely explanation is that you haven't declared that resource within a scope that can be accessed by your xaml. You'll want to create a `StaticResource` with a key matching the name you're referencing, within a `Resources` section of your xaml, the exact location may vary depending on your needs/structure.

Assuming you're doing this within a `Window`, you could do something like:

```
   <Window>
      <Window.Resources>
         <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
      </Window.Resources>
      <Grid Visibility="{Binding isZoneTwoVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">

         <--...Content...-->

      </Grid>
   </Window>
```

Note: I haven't included your namespace in front of the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` because this is a class which [already exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) within the framework.

It may be the case you require slightly different behaviour, or don't have access to that class, in which case you may need to add your namespace when defining the resource, e.g. `<HelperObjects:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>`

Potentially useful further info about static resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension

Comment: This is on a Page.xaml resource.   have this setup in the Page.Resource.  There are no errors, but I don't understand what your 'Binding True' is supposed to do.  Shouldn't I bind this to a specific variable?

Comment: Sorry, that was just me typing something to fill out the answer, your property binding was fine. I'll update it to match your property name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the converter in UserControlResources or even parent level Grid Resources. Assuming you are using a UserControl.
And your code is unclear as of where you are defining the StaticResource BoolToVisConverter. But generally heres the process.

Look at this sample code below to define your StaticResorce in the UserControl Resources section. Make sure you set the **DataContext** where isZoneTwoVisible is residing. I am hoping you implemented ImplementINotifyPropertyChanged and said PropertyChanged on your isZoneTwoVisible or isZoneTwoVisible is a DependencyProperty. **Note:** BooleanToVisibilityConverter is a class that implements an IValueConverter or if your property is a bool you don't even need that class.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter
                x:Key="boolToVisibility"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
        </UserControl.Resources>
```

You did all the things said above and it still dosen't work, sometimes I specify the relative Source hoping its residing in a UserControl.

```
Visibility="{Binding isZoneTwoVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility},RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```